# error on installing mytop : Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16

Tags: linux, mysql, monitoring, installation

my mysql cpu usage has been high lately

so i'm trying to installl mytop to monitor the database

when i try to install it with yum i get this :

```
yum -y install mytop 

    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
    Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

i have mysql 5.5.x installed and apparently

```
libmysqlclient.so.16 is provided by MySQL 5.1 packages
```

so what should i do ? should i downgrade mysql version ? which doesn't seem logical .

is there any other tool that i can use instead of `mytop` ?

i've tried

```
yum -y install mytop --skip-broken
```

didn't work

what does this do ?

```
rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

i'm kinda newbie , i dont want to mess anything up .

Comment: Go back to whoever you got your MySQL packages from.

Comment: @MichaelHampton he's not available at the moment